# File location for new CiviRules Action

Tags: civirules

I have written a new CiviRules Action and added the entry to the database but I don't know where to put the php file. I have read all the documents I can find but I can't find any information about a directory structure for rules addons. I would like to keep it as part of an extension I have written. Any help with the file location would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put it in your own extension, under the CRM folder and subfolders you need to create depending on the class name. See https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/#step-2-add-a-class-that-extends-crm_civirule_action

```
You can include the class file in the Civirules extension if you want,
but you can also include it in your own extension. This class should extend
CRM_Civirules_Action to be able to add your action to the CiviRules Engine
```

So let's say your class is CRM_Mynamespace_CivirulesActions_Contact_Subtype, then you'd call the file Subtype.php and put it in your extension in CRM/Mynamespace/CivirulesActions/Contact

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is the first time I have seen it documented that the Class name is anything other than a random collection of joined words. I suppose it is sort of obvious when you are told but how was I to know? Maybe the text you highlight above should also say "and the class name determines the path to the file containing the new class". I have accepted your answer. Thank you

Comment: Up to a point the class name is a random collection of joined words. The file path is a standard PHP PSR-4 autoloader rule. The CRM_Mynamespace part is a little specific to where civi extensions look for files and the convention that civix uses, but otherwise the part after it can be whatever you want. You could do `CRM_Mynamespace_Grapple_Grommit_Foo extends CRM_Civirules_Action` and put the Foo.php file in CRM/Mynamespace/Grapple/Grommit. Often you would do `civix generate:XXX`, and then it makes the files for you, there just isn't an XXX command for CiviRules, but it's the same pattern.